# Top sheet like chrome app?

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3B8m4.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hqNu.png]

I am currently using a `bottomSheetFragment` in my app for showing quick settings.
I want also provide info like chrome app does when you click the ssl icon. So is this behavior can be achieved using bottom-sheet?

Comment: a bottom sheet is for showing things at the bottom, so no

Comment: this may helps you https://github.com/Tapadoo/Alerter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this Lib

> https://github.com/orhanobut/dialogplus

Can add Dialog at Top.

[image]

**Gradle**

```
compile 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.11@aar'
```